# How to open jquery dialog box on page onload event

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

Here is the complete code. I want to open this dialog box on page load event instead of click. Please assist me on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a { 
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#00c6ff;
}

h1 {
    font: 4em normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;  margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

h2 {
    color:#bbb;
    font-size:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 1px 3px #161616;
}

#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000; 
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}

.login-popup{
    display:none;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;  
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Safari, Chrome */
}

img.btn_close {
    float: right; 
    margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.login-window').click(function() {

        // Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="btn-sign">
        <h2><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Click me to Open the dialog box</a></h2>
        </div>

        <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
         <h1>This is a dialog box !</h1> 
         <p>How to load it on page load event?</p>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the complete code. I want to open this dialog box on page load event instead of click. Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$('a.login-window').click(function() {` (and corresponding `}`. That way the DOM ready call will open it. You also need to change `var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');` to `var loginBox = $('.login-window').attr('href');`. `.live()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()` in jQuery 1.7. And remove the first `return false;` that you used to cancel the click event. Of course, this will only show the dialog on load and not onlick but you did say "I want to open this dialog box on page load event instead of click", not "in addition to".

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4NWH4/)**

```
// Getting the variable's value from a link 
var loginBox = $('.login-window').attr('href');

//Fade in the Popup and add close button
$(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

//Set the center alignment padding + border
var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

$(loginBox).css({
    'margin-top': -popMargTop,
        'margin-left': -popMargLeft
});

// Add the mask to body
$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(300);

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').on('click', function () {
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: NOt working. Can you please show me demo on jsfiddle or anywhere else..or paste the complete working code

Comment: You're right, there was a little more to it. Updating answer.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working with me. But again it's not working on local system.

Comment: Yes fiddle is working. But local is not working. See below consolidated fiddle code, what i am using on local.

Comment: I found the issue. It's working now..I was missing jquery 1.9.1 to call on the page. Thank you very much for your time and resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the click handler that's wrapped around the initialization code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').on('click', function() { 
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
});
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.9, the `live` function has been removed, so you will need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hi cfs. I used your given code. But not working..Can you please look again and try it out on jsfiddle or anywhere else to see..

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Getting the variable's value from a link 
var loginBox = $('.login-window').attr('href');

//Fade in the Popup and add close button
$(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

//Set the center alignment padding + border
var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

$(loginBox).css({
    'margin-top': -popMargTop,
        'margin-left': -popMargLeft
});

// Add the mask to body
$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(300);



// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').on('click', function () {
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
<style>
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#00c6ff;
}
h1 {
    font: 4em normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
h2 {
    color:#bbb;
    font-size:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 1px 3px #161616;
}
#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}
.login-popup {
    display:none;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Safari, Chrome */
}
img.btn_close {
    float: right;
    margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn-sign">
     <h2><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Click me to Open the dialog box</a></h2>

</div>
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup"> <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>

     <h1>This is a dialog box !</h1> 
    <p>How to load it on page load event?</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```